# Java Replacing a Character with a Character

Tags: java, replace, character, capitalization

I am learning Java on my own and practicing using online exercises. I have only learned up until methods thus far so using an array for this exercise is beyond my scope, even though several solutions online use arrays to do what I want.

The exercise is this: Have the user enter a string with vowels. Wherever there is a vowel letter, display that vowel as a capital letter.

Example: If the user enters "apples", the correct output is ApplEs

I have this code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CapitalizeVowels {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a string ~ ");
        String string = keyboard.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(string.charAt(i));
            if (string.charAt(i) == 'a' || 
                string.charAt(i) == 'e' || 
                string.charAt(i) == 'i' || 
                string.charAt(i) == 'o' || 
                string.charAt(i) == 'u') {

                char upperCaseVowel = Character.toUpperCase(string.charAt(i));
                System.out.print(upperCaseVowel);

                // need to replace string.charAt(i) with upperCaseVowel
                // find something to replace characters
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my code as it is, with the input string "apples", for example, I get "aAppleEs" as my output. Both the lower case vowels and the upper case vowels are being printed. I am thinking that I should replace string.charAt(i) which is the lower case vowel with upperCaseVowel but I can't find any replace() method or something to that effect for characters. I tried other things like StringBuilder, etc. but I haven't come across a solution that is simple enough to avoid arrays as I didn't learn them yet. Any help on how I can get to the proper output is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [There's a replace method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29).

Comment: Do not print the character at the $i^{th}$ position until after checking if it's a vowel.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is printing every character before testing if it's a vowel.

Instead, print each char after you've figured out what it should be. The body of your loop should be:

```
char next = string.charAt(i);
if (next == 'a' || 
    next == 'e' || 
    next == 'i' || 
    next == 'o' || 
    next == 'u') {
    next = Character.toUpperCase(next);
}
System.out.print(next);
```

You may consider adding:

```
else {
    next = Character.toLowerCase(next);
}
```

To enforce non vowels being lower case.

Comment: This is another great way that I wouldn't have thought of until after great thought. :P

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the `Sysout` prior to `if` statement to `else`, to avoid printing same character twice, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string ~ ");
    String string = keyboard.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        if (string.charAt(i) == 'a' || string.charAt(i) == 'e' || string.charAt(i) == 'i' || string.charAt(i) == 'o'
                || string.charAt(i) == 'u') {

            char upperCaseVowel = Character.toUpperCase(string.charAt(i));
            System.out.print(upperCaseVowel);

            // need to replace string.charAt(i) with upperCaseVowel
            // find something to replace characters
        }else{
            System.out.print(string.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh! I see. I had the algorithm done correctly but I didn't print out logically...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
class ReplaceVowel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String words = "apples";
        char converted = 0;
        String w = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
            if (words.charAt(i) =='a'|| words.charAt(i)=='e'||words.charAt(i)=='i'||words.charAt(i)=='o'||words.charAt(i)=='u') {
                converted = Character.toUpperCase(words.charAt(i));
                w = words.replace(words.charAt(i), converted);
                words = w;
                    
            } else {
                converted = Character.toUpperCase(words.charAt(i));
                w = words.replace(words.charAt(i), converted);
                words = w;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```